# How i can import only one time dependencies for many file javascript?

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack

Hey i'm doing a wordpress plugin and i have two important files. Index.js and functions.js.
When i import like jquery dependency in index.js, i have an error and i need to import it into functions.js too.

I want to import it only one time, how i can do that ?

Thanks for your help !

imports of my index.js ->

```
import * as ui from 'jquery-ui';
import * as leaflet from 'leaflet';
import * as leafletAjax from 'leaflet-ajax';
import * as d3Array from 'd3-array';
import * as d3Geo from 'd3-geo';

import * as f from './fonctions.js';
```

Comment: Why do you not want to import it in both files? Does it cause an error, or unexpected behavior?

Comment: I use jquery in both files, functions.js and index.js. But functions.js is imported in index.js and i still need to import jquery in both. But i want to import it only one time.

Comment: Jquery is a exemple but i have a lot of dependencies and files to import many times

Comment: You did not answer my question. Do you actually get any bugs currently? Is the website lagging because of the imports? I don't think what you want to do is reasonable. If everything is working as intended, then you don't need to remove any imports.

Comment: When i want to modify the value of an variable from functions.js in index.js i have this error Uncaught TypeError: setting getter-only property. But except that that seems to work. That the classic way to multiply import in files ?